# Help finding paths

Tags: search, prolog

```
% link(Origin,Destination,Speed,Length).
link(paris,milano,140,360).
link(paris,london,200,698).
link(berlin,atena,110,714).
link(atena,paris,90,370).
```

I need to write this route predicate so I get a `Path` from city X to city Y.

```
route(Origin,Destination,TrainType,Path,Length,Duration).
```

I am new to Prolog, so I wrote something like this. I know it's not correct:

```
route(Origin,Destination,TrainType,Path,Legth,Duration) :-
    link(Origin,City,Len),
    City \= Origin,
    NewLen is Length + Len,
    route(City,Destination,TrainType,Path,NewLen,Duration).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate lacks a *base case*, that tells it when to stop. Right now, your predicate will always call itself until it fails (or worse, loops indefinitely, depending on your `link` predicate). The following gives you a reverse path:

```
route(Goal, Goal, Path, Path).  % base case
route(From, To, Path0, Path) :-
    direct_link(From, Via),
    route(Via, To, [From|Path0], Path).
```

where a direct link means you can get from A to B; I'm assuming railways are bidirectional:

```
direct_link(A,B) :- link(A, B, _Speed, _Length).
direct_link(B,A) :- link(B, A, _Speed, _Length).
```

You will need to call `reverse` on the path and add arguments to keep track of length and duration. I'll leave that as an exercise.